# Reporting Service Toolbar Items Location Issue

Tags: reporting-services

I have developed a report using SQL reporting service 2008 and deploy it For my tests, I used internet explorer and I do not have any problem but my customer sees icons like the following figure (even he uses internet explorer).

How can I fix it. If not possible, then how to remove completely toolbar?

(I used some parameters in URL but when I click query button, toolbar appears again)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution

http://sqlblog.net/2014/04/18/sql-server-reporting-services-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11/

I do not know yet if it works.. my customer is going to try it.